# Laravel:send email to the address dynamically

Tags: laravel, callback, laravel-5.3, email

in default registration form i am taking input of name email password and status is default 0.my email is sending but from me to me..i want to send the email address from the email that was entered in the time of registration to the email id i gave.i tried like this...

```
  <?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
  use Mail;
  use App\User;
  use Validator;
  use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
  use DB; 
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

  class RegisterController extends Controller
  {

    use RegistersUsers;

  protected $redirectTo = '/regmessage';

  public function __construct()
  {
      $this->middleware('guest');
  }


   protected function validator(array $data)
   {
           return Validator::make($data, [
          'name' => 'required|max:255',
          'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
          'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
          /*'usertype' => 'required',*/
         ]);
   }


  protected function create(array $data)
  {
          $user=User::create([
          'name' => $data['name'],
          'email' => $data['email'],
          'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
          /*'usertype' =>$data['usertype'],*/
          'status' => 0,
         ]);
       $use = array('name' => 'Admin');


   Mail::send('emailMessage', $use, function ($m) use ($data){

    $m->from($data['email'])
     ->to('mrbbangladesh2017@gmail.com')
     ->subject('Confirm email');
      });

     return $user;
    }
   }
```

Comment: I hope you are using google smtp to send the email, Google smtp cannot send email from anonymous sender. It will send the mail from only verified senders.

Comment: i am using this in .env which is a valid id....is there anything need to change here? `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mrbbangladesh2017@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`

Comment: and i am also giving valid mail id which will be used as 'from mail id'

Comment: This means you can send email from mrbbangladesh2017@gmail.com only, means your from should be like this,  $m->from('mrbbangladesh2017@gmail.com'); but If you want your registered user in reply to parameter you can have that, But from should math what ever you have in .env variable.

Comment: but i want to sent from the address that is using for registration and 'mrbbangladesh2017@gmail.com' is the reciever

Comment: To make this using SMTP driver you need use mail_username, mail_password, mail_host dynamic. And with the information of the owner of email.

Answer (score 0):

Try below `create()` function code:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user=User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        /*'usertype' =>$data['usertype'],*/
        'status' => 0,
    ]);
    $use = array('name' => 'Admin', 'userEmail' => $data['email']);


    Mail::send('emailMessage', $use, function ($m) use ($use){

        $m->from($use['userEmail'])
            ->to('mrbbangladesh2017@gmail.com')
            ->subject('Confirm email');
    });

    return $user;
}
```

This should be work!

Comment: not working this is my email showing `from: mrbbangladesh2017@gmail.com
to: mrbbangladesh2017@gmail.com
date: Thu, Jan 12, 2017 at 4:57 PM
subject: Confirm email
mailed-by: gmail.com
: Important mainly because it was sent directly to you.`